# Botman stopped replying in messenger

Tags: laravel, facebook-messenger-bot, botman

I am getting this error:

```
Error sending payload: The user must be an administrator, editor, or moderator of the page in order to impersonate it. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication. {"exception":"[object] (BotMan\\Drivers\\Facebook\\Exceptions\\FacebookException(code: 0)
```

my Botman Laravel was working normally but it stopped suddenly with the mentioned message in Laravel log.

first, what does this error mean, why it happened, and how to fix that

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

although the problem wasn't clearly referred to the access token, the problem solved by changing Facebook access token